# task scheduler powershell foreground

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

I am using windows server 2016 "scheduled tasks" to run a powershell script.

For some reason, i would see the script run in foreground , and not in background.

Any idea to resolv this ?

Thanks

Comment: Use "Run whether a user is logged on or not"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the script running, you have to configure the task to run with your credentials AND to run only if you are logged-on.

In the Task Scheduler: open the task properties, go to the General tab. Here, you can select "Run only when user is logged on".

If you don't want to see the script running, you can check "Run whether a user is logged on or not"

Comment: its work like a charm , thank you men